# How good are lvl 50 amiibos are perfect shielding?

Tags: super-smash-bros-4, amiibo

I have a Kirby Amiibo with `Easy Perfect Shield`, `Shield Mirror`, and `Exploading Perfect Shield`.  He's very difficult to hit because he times his perfect shield probably 3 in 4 times if he's on the ground and not mid-swing.

I'm considering replacing `Easy Perfect Shield` with a Healer Shield item.  I don't know how often he shields perfectly because he's a computer vs how often he does it because he has the `Easy Perfect Shield` buff.  I'm afraid to test it, because I don't have another `Easy Perfect Shield` item should he become less effective.

Can anyone give me an idea of about how often max level amiibos time their perfect shield naturally?

Comment: Assuming that "lv50 amiibo" translates into "lv9 CPU", he'll have a 1-frame reaction time for everything (also assuming the AI works at least similar to Brawl's), which means "how often" would be "however often a lv9 CPU decides to perfect shield". I would guess 90%. But there's too many assumptions here to post as an answer.

Comment: Fair enough.  I'm pretty sure lv50 amiibos have faster "reflexes" than level 9 computers.  I'll keep my Easy Perfect Shield then.

Comment: Amiibos are, generally, smarter than CPUs at max level because of how they adapt to gameplay.

Comment: CPUs also learn from your habits, but yeah I think the amiibos do this more than CPUs do.

Answer (score 3):

I highly suggest you switch to the other item, these Amiibos are *very smart pieces of technology* that develop whenever they lose or win. So if you do decide to switch, try switching to a character like Mario, or Luigi and keep pressuring them with their fireballs. Kirby will eventually learn if you take the time and patience to teach it.

Comment: It's interesting to note that amiibos may not "learn" from playing, their skill might just scale with level like normal CPUs, see this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VE3FGrw1Ukk